# Implementing SQL function STR

Tags: c#, performance, strings, sql, formatting

I am writing a piece of code in c# that mimics the behaviour of following SQL function STR in the following case:

```
declare @number numeric(19,15)    = 219.37345462345234235
SELECT str(@number,9,9) -- 219.37345

declare @number numeric(19,15)    = 19.37345462345234235
SELECT str(@number,9,9) -- 19.373455
```

Following is an input output table for this scenario:

[image: InputOutput]

I have implemented the following function in C# which accepts a double variable and returns a string which is equal to the result returned by the SQL function `STR(@number,9,9)`.

```
public static string GetCustomStringQuantity(double quantity)
    {
        string customQuantity ;
        int length = (int) Math.Log10(Math.Abs(quantity))+1;
        if (length>9)
            return "*********";
        quantity = Math.Round(quantity, 8 - length,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);            
        customQuantity = quantity.ToString();  
        customQuantity= (quantity %1==0)?(customQuantity+".").PadRight(9, '0'):customQuantity.PadRight(9, '0');            

        if (customQuantity.Length > 9)
            customQuantity = customQuantity.Substring(0, 9);
        else if (customQuantity.Length == 9 && customQuantity.EndsWith("."))
            customQuantity = customQuantity.Substring(0, 8);

        return customQuantity; 
    }
```

How can I make this function better? Or is there a better way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the `length` of the integer portion, you can use the `fx` format specifier to get the correct number of decimals, which would clean up the string building part.

```
 return quantity.ToString("f" + (8 - length));
```

That should clean up the code some.

As I started typing that, I figured I'd check for edge cases too - since `STR` is filled with them (eg., it includes the negative sign in the length, returns `**` if it overflows, etc.). You're handling the `**` case, but a couple of edge-case values fail:

```
 Input       | Expected  | Actual
 999999999.5 | ********* | 1000000000
 123456789   | 123456789 | ArgOutOfRangeException
 123456789.5 | 123456790 | ArgOutOfRangeException
 -123456789  | ********* | ArgOutOfRangeException
```

I'd advise that if you're looking for 100% compatibility with `STR` here, you'll probably want some extensive unit tests.

Here's what I came up with that handles the edge-cases I threw at it, but I don't expect it's bullet proof either. Main changes are using the format specifier, and using `.ToString` to get the number of digits before the decimal place instead of `Log10`.

```
 public static string GetCustomStringQuantity(double quantity) {
    const int LENGTH = 9;
    // Include negative sign, just like STR()
    int numberOfIntDigits = Math.Round(quantity, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString().Length;
    if (numberOfIntDigits == LENGTH) return quantity.ToString("f0");
    if (numberOfIntDigits > LENGTH) return new string('*', LENGTH);

    int numberOfDecimals = LENGTH - numberOfIntDigits - 1; // include 1 for the decimal place
    return quantity.ToString("f" + numberOfDecimals); // uses MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero
}
```